# Is doInBackground Cancelled when dialog dismisses?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a custom progress dialog within an AsyncTask which acts as a download progress, I want to interrupt doInBackground when my custom cancel button pressed. It seems when the dialog dismisses, doInBackground resumes without any problems!

Answer (score 1):

You could call `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` from the cancel event of the dialog. For this you do need a reference to the AsyncTask, this could be an instance variable initialized when the task is started. Then in the `asyncTask.doInBackground()` method you can check for `isCancelled()`, or override the `onCancelled()` method and stop the running task there.

Example:

```
//Asynctask instance variable
private YourAsyncTask asyncTask;

//Starting the asynctask
public void startAsyncTask(){
   asyncTask = new YourAsyncTask();
   asyncTask.execute();
}

//Dialog code
loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ThisActivity.this,
                                               "",
                                               "Loading. Please wait...",
                                               false,
                                               true,
                                               new OnCancelListener()
                                               {

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
                                                 {
                                                   if (asyncTask != null)
                                                   {
                                                     asyncTask.cancel(true);
                                                   }
                                                 }
                                               });
```

EDIT: If you create the dialog from inside the AsyncTask, the code would not be very different. You probably wouldn't need the instance variable, I think you could call YourAsyncTask.this.cancel(true) in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
I want to interrupt doInBackground when my custom cancel button pressed.
```

=> call **`cancel()`** method of your AsyncTask inside the cancel button click event. Now this is not enough to cancel doInBackground() process.

For example:

```
 asyncTask.cancel(true);
```

To notify that you have cancelled AsyncTask using cancel() method, you have to check whether its cancelled or not using **`isCancelled()` inside `doInBackground()`**.

For example:

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) 
{
  // do your work...

   if (isCancelled())  
       break;

}
```